# Reason to have a member reference variable over a member pointer variable

Tags: c++

What is a practical example and reason to store a reference to an object instead of a pointer? The obvious reason I can come up with is to avoid memory management.

I've come across a library where sometimes a class will store an object by reference and sometimes by pointer and it's difficult for me to understand why and when to use one over the other?

Example:

```
class EventBusDemo : public Object
{
private:
    HandlerRegistration* playerMoveReg; 
};

class PlayerMoveEvent : public Event
{
private:
    Player& player;  // Why not a pointer here?
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The key points are that the identity of the object a reference points to can not be changed (its values can though), and a reference can not be null (but you can still get dangling references if you're not careful)

So if you see code like this:

```
class ObjectWithPointer
{
private:
    Object* object; 
};
```

You might need to do this:

```
void useIt(ObjectWithPointer & value) {
   if(value.object!=NULL) {
      doSomethingWith(*value.object);
   }
}
```

And you can also do this:

```
void modifyIt(ObjectWithPointer & value) {
   value.object!= some_object_ptr;
}
```

However if you have this:

```
class ObjectWithRef
{
private:
    Object& object; 
};
```

The first example becomes:

```
void useIt(ObjectWithRef & value) {
   doSomethingWith(value.object);
}
```

And the a naive conversion of the second

```
void modifyIt(ObjectWithRef & value) {
   value.object=some_object;
}
```

does something completely different - it copies the value of some_object into the reference, but there is no way to cause the reference to point somewhere else.

Comment: a referenced object can be changed cant it? player.setX(n); will change that object passed by reference (in the constructor of PlayMoveEvent)?

Comment: @JakeM updated the code to clarify what happens with reference object. You cant change where the reference points, but you can change the values inside that reference.

Answer (score 0):

The better question is "Why would you use a pointer instead of a reference?". Generally, you should only use a pointer when you can actually answer this question.

---

For the purposes of referring to something, a pointer requires slightly more cumbersome syntax to use. Also, you can do more with a pointer than you can with a reference, like change where it's pointing, which is a Bad Thing if you aren't actually doing any of that. Any savvy reader who sees your pointer will be forced to consider all sorts of things that they wouldn't do if you had used a reference, like wonder if you remembered to initialized it, or wonder if you change what it's pointing to, et cetera.

It probably impairs compiler optimizations too, since the compiler has to wonder about the same things!

Comment: There's also a matter of clarity. It's not immediately obvious to the caller that they're passing by reference and not by value, not without inspecting the definition of the function. If they're passing by pointer, they know at once that the function is getting access to the original object, and lots of things may happen to it. A common convention I've seen is to pass only by constant reference (const obj& o) if you just need the reference and won't alter the original object, and by pointer otherwise. I'm not sure that's a good convention but it's another consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in class `X` a `reference to object` rather than pointers, `X` can be happy to think that the object is `local`. It is somewhere in the stack. `X` does not have to think about its destruction `definitely`. With pointers, the object would be on the heap. Programmer (and especially maintainer of `X`) might get confused about who would free this pointer. So, peace of mind with references. This point is valid when comparing `reference-to-object-on-heap` and `pointer-to-object-on-stack`.

There comes then another problem, `dangling references and dangling pointers`.

Since, anybody can call a delete on a pointer from any place, it is difficult to find the actual cause of dangling pointers. Not with dangling references. Since, that object would be destroyed when it went out of stack, there is only one place in code where that can happen (it is where that object was created).
So, it is easier to find the problem.

If you get a dangling reference, there is something wrong in design. As you are storing an object `Y`'s reference in `X`. `X` is using `Y`. However, lifetime of `X` is greater than `Y`. This can happen when `Y` is local and `X` is global. This is counter-intuitive because why would in the stack you would store the reference of upper-stack-object in lower-stack-object.
But with dangling pointers, there can be wrong logic-error or ownership mismatch. So, if problem like dangling reference comes, it can be fixed with better design.

However, if we are storing the object on heap as a reference, it would be difficult to find the dangling-reference problem again.

So, my priority would be :

```
references to stack object > references to heap object > pointers.
```

Looking at your code and guessing : `EventBusDemo` is like some global bus that stores the registration-handler that would be called. Here this is one object and you would be giving it different `playerMoveReg` over time. So, it is a pointer.

`PlayerMoveEvent` looks like it would be processed soon as it is an `Event`. You would create a new `PlayerMoveEvent` for a new event. So, do you want to make `player` a pointer or a reference. Do you want to change the `player` in a event (even by mistake) ? Definitely not. Do you want some piece of mind ? Definitely yes. So, use a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is almost always matter of taste. You can use reference for class members when you want emphasize that one object is not owner of other object or if you want avoid runtime check for null-pointer. Every approach has cons and pros, but in my practice I avoid use reference as object members because you can't reassign their values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a pointer then:

```
void PlayerMoveEvent::Foo()
{
  // can it be null? its possible because its a pointer!
  if (player) player->bar(); 
}

PlayerMoveEvent::~PlayerMoveEvent()
{
   // crash? or memory leak with out?
   delete player;
}
```

A reference makes it clear that it will be valid for the life time of the object (or at least that is the intention) and that you do not own the object. Always use a reference unless a pointer is *really* required.